# Is there a way to batch-remove a tag?

Tags: support, tags, moderator-abilities

Moderators can batch-merge or batch-rename a tag, but is there a way to batch-remove a tag?

- If there is such a way, what happens to questions in which the removed tag is the only tag?
- If there isn't such a way, is there any alternative to completely manual retagging of all the affected questions?

Comment: _chirp chirp chirp . . ._